# Seeking Russian Orthodox Church Records 1840-1900 for Lagody, Poland/Russia (now Belarus)?

Tags: 19th-century, poland, russia, parish-register, belarus

My grandfather was born in 1885 at Lagody/Lagodi, Poland/Russia (Vilna/Wilna gubernia) and came to USA 1911.

Lagody/Lagoda/Lahady is now in Belarus (Hrodna/Grodno province) and is still a small village (3.7 miles from Shchuchin and 50-60 miles from Hrodna/Grodno, Belarus).

The Russian Orthodox parish records are not in the archives of Grodno, Belarus.

My 2nd Great Grandfather was born around 1830 (I know his first name & the names of 3 children).

My Great Grandfather born around 1860 (I know the names of 9 children & births of 4 children & 3 grandchildren). They all lived in Lagody.

Would these records be in Poland, Russia, Lithuania or Belarus?

My surname is spelled different and I can provide:

1. Name written in "Old Russian" on 1913 passport.
2. Name written 2 ways on US immigration records.
3. Current spelling used by a relative living in Lagody/Lagoda/Lahady, Belarus.

Comment: This is more than one question.  Please post questions separately.  Asking for contacts who could perform searches is off-topic.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than multiple questions in one.

Comment: I have reduced the scope of your question to a single question.  I have removed the parts which seem to be an advertisement to try and engage a researcher and are off-topic as indicated by @Chenmunka.

Answer (score 4):

Lahady didn't have their own orthodox church, so their parish was in Szchuchin (Shchuchin) - foto of the church [here](http://www.radzima.net/be/prihod/shchuchinskiy.html), and you need records of the church in Shchuchin.

Records of this parish are in different archives.

1. In Lithuanian National Archive - only baptisms of 1889 year. You can look through them [here](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-89G9-FRN?mode=g)
2. In National Belarussian Archive in Minsk - years 1845, 1860. Fond 246, inventory 1.
3. In National Belarussian Archive in Grodno - years 1872-1881, 1889-1893,1901-1904, 1912-1913,1915, 1922-1939 гг.

Archives of Poland have records about Grodno gubernia, but mostly they are jewish records.

Comment: Just piggybacking here to say that I have ordered and received records from the Grodno archives before, and although it took them months to actually deliver the records, they gave me a wealth of information. It's worth following up on. Write your e-mail to them in very simplistic language and use short sentences, then translate it all with Google Translate online, then e-mail them both the Belarusian text and the English text below it.  (You can also e-mail them in Russian, but given the political sensibilities in the area, I think trying to use Belarusian would be more welcome.)